# first do slideup and fadeout on two html element then continue

Tags: jquery, fadeout, slideup

I must slideup modalbox-dialog and also fadout modalbox-overlay and that must occur on the same time so its not possible to do the fade out in the done function of slideup

```
$('#modalbox-dialog').slideUp({
    done:function() {

    }
});

$('#modalbox-overlay').fadeOut();
```

after slideup and fadeout are done these things must be performed

```
$('.nav > *').remove();
$('#foo-helper > *').remove();
$(FilterView.currentDiv).insertAfter('#hidden-divs-helper');
FilterView.currentDiv = '';
```

Comment: You could put a duration on both animations and also put a delay on the slide up animation that is equal to the duration. So they both run at the same time.

Comment: I've first programmed it with setTimeout and the executed the second codeblock after 400ms because the duration is 400 but I'd like to make a cross-over solution ... so that I mustn't change always the settimeout time

Comment: Don't use timeout. Use the properties of slideUp and fadeOut. Check the docs for usage

Comment: Or you could use the progress callback and fire your slide Up on the first progress call. Again check the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var f1 = $('#modalbox-dialog').slideUp({duration:10000})
    var f2 = $('#modalbox-overlay').fadeOut();

    $.when( f1, f2 ).done(function ( v1, v2 ) {
        alert('finished both');
    });
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oLm8L1pL/

I set the duration extra high to demonstrate the effect.

Answer (score 0):

that's my solution

```
hide: function () {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var slideUp = $('#modalbox-dialog').slideUp();
    var fadeOut = $('#modalbox-overlay').fadeOut();

    $.when(slideUp, fadeOut).done(function() {
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

hope it helps for further questions:)